# Fabric.js: front and back views

Tags: fabricjs

How to implement front and back side canvas elements? (I mean when creating business card/t-shirt designer app).
If I use Serialization / Deserialization to change the active canvas elements how to determine to which canvas objects will be added?

Comment: this might be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/fpHaE/  or https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/520

Answer (score 1):

Solved..
I put the canvas elements into divs. (for example: #container1, #container2);

Hid `#container2`;

Then in JS made two variables like that:

```
var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');
```

Then assigned to `canvas` `canvas1` or `canvas2` variables.
Thus we can active the canvas we want..

Here's the whole part:

```
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('c2');

    var switcher = 1;

    if(switcher == 1) {
        var canvas = canvas1;
        $("#container2").hide();
            fireEvents();
    }

    $("#bside").click(function(){
        switcher = 2;
        $("#container1").hide()
        $("#container2").show();
            fireEvents();
        canvas = canvas2;
        canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
        canvas.calcOffset();
    });
    $("#fside").click(function(){
        switcher = 1;
        $("#container1").show()
        $("#container2").hide();
            fireEvents();
        canvas = canvas1;
        canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();
        canvas.calcOffset();
    }); 

function fireEvents(){
canvas.on('object:selected', function(options){
 // Event actions
});
}
```

used `canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();` to disable selected objects from previus active canvas and `fireEvents()` function to apply fired events to the both canvases.. (don't feel that's the right way to do it though...)

Comment: i tried this way, but page get too havy and loading canvases is very slow, object selection is also very slow.